# c# nested json to object (current with json.net)

Tags: c#, json, oop, json.net

i am new to c# and json.net. 
I have a json configuration file and try to parse it to objects. But how can i map the relations correctly in the objects? 
Currently the property in project loop is null.
And can the objects map "automatically" without mapping each property name/value?
I can also change the json!

configuration.json:

```
{
  "debug": true,
  "log": "database",
  "projects": [
    {
      "name": "Name 1",
      "showInfo": false,
      "ranges": [
        [
          5,
          6
        ],
        [
          9,
          10
        ],
        [
          15,
          20
        ]
      ],
      "additional": [
        {
          "name": "subName 1",
          "parameter": "ID"
        },
        {
          "name": "subName 2",
          "parameter": "ID2"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Name 2",
      "showInfo": false,
      "ranges": [
        [
          99,
          100
        ]
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Name 3",
      "showInfo": false,
      "ranges": [
        [
          44,
          45
        ]
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Name 4",
      "showInfo": false,
      "ranges": [
        [
          12,
          14
        ]
      ],
      "additional": [
        {
          "name": "subName xy",
          "parameter": "ID"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

my try to parse:

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText(filePath));

if (jObject.ContainsKey("debug"))
{
    configuration.Debug = (bool) jObject["debug"];
}
if (jObject.ContainsKey("log"))
{
    configuration.Log = (string) jObject["log"];
}

//loop projects
JToken projects = jObject["projects"];

foreach (JToken child in projects.Children())
{
    var property = child as JProperty;
    if (property != null)
    {
        var test = property.Name;
        var test2 = property.Value;
    }
}
```

the objects:

```
public class Configuration
{
    public bool Debug { get; set; } = false;
    public string Log { get; set; }
    // this is propably wrong
    public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Project>> Projects { get; set; }
}

public class Project
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public bool showInfo{ get; set; }
    // wrong?
    public int[,] ranges { get; set; }
    // wrong?
    public Additional[] Additional{ get; set; }
}
public class Additional
{
   public string Name{ get; set; }
   public string Parameter { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `var property = child as JProperty;` needs to be `var property = child as JObject;` but i would go with the answer given by Filip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a `JObject` at all json files can be desterilized to objects it's much more efficient because you don't create unneeded objects.
You Config class is just wrong

```
public class Configuration
    {
        public bool Debug { get; set; }
        public string Log { get; set; }
        public Project[] Projects { get; set; }
    }

    public class Project
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool ShowInfo { get; set; }
        public int[][] Ranges { get; set; }
        public Additional[] Additional { get; set; }
    }

    public class Additional
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Parameter { get; set; }
    }`
```

Should look like this.
And then use. `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Configuration>(json);` To get the object.
If you have Visual studio it has this cool feature called paste special where you can just past your json and it will create a proper class for deserialization. It's under Edit-> Paste special-> Paste json as class